# ASP.NET Menu Item hover image

Tags: asp.net, menu, menuitem

I have an asp.net menu with multiple menuitems. How can I overlay an image over the menu item text when the mouse is over the item? Secondly, how can I display a different overlay image when the menu item is selected?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you are trying to do by using the various [MenuItemStyles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.menuitemstyle%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) like so:

```
<asp:Menu ID="menu" runat="server">
    <DynamicSelectedStyle CssClass="menu-item-selected" />
    <StaticSelectedStyle CssClass="menu-item-selected" />
    <StaticHoverStyle CssClass="menu-item-hover" />
    <DynamicHoverStyle CssClass="menu-item-hover" />
    <Items>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="Item 1" Selectable="true" Selected="true"></asp:MenuItem>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="Item 2" Selectable="true"></asp:MenuItem>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="Item 3" Selectable="true"></asp:MenuItem>
    </Items>
</asp:Menu>
```

Hope this helps.